# Error in pubsyaml in flutter to add image tag

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does this error is happen?

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 62, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
   ╷
62 │    assets:
   │    ^
   ╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Flutter\chirag\Image Flutter\image_flutter\pubspec.yaml
Exited (1)
```

Comment: Can you attach your your `pubspec.yaml` file to the question? The error message is about this file is not correct formatted.